# Problem with AC powered system

Tags: motor, ac, load

I have a system (car simulator) which is powered by a 220Vac 60Hz. Within the system there are 6 switched sources, 4 of 24 Vdc, 1 of 12Vdc and 1 of 5Vcd. Loads 1,2 and 3 are dc motors 24vcd. Loads 4,5 and 6 are other peripherals of the system. The GND of all switched sources are on. Some problems listed below are happening.

• Sometimes I hit some metal part of the system (simulator) and I take a small shock.
• When one of the motors requires the current close to the source capacity, the system starts to fail.

I wonder if the system below has the correct links. Should I put some kind of filter on the system road or in the engines?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTWGW7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: More info needed.  How is the system earthed?  How are the loads switched?  Do the supplies require a minimum load (many do)?  Are the DC grounds earthed?  What are the constant-full-load specs of the problematic supply?  What are the specs of the motor/load?  What type of cooling?  Possible inadvertent load sharing among supplies (many supplies do not like this)?  Motors have a high inrush (startup) current, are your motor supplies spec'd for this (if the motor rating and the power supply ratings are close, then the supply may trip-off)?

Comment: All sources are connected to Earth.
The sources have a capacity of 10A.
GND from all sources are connected to each other, but are not connected to the Earth (I think connecting the GND of the output which is direct current to Earth does not make sense).
The system is cooled by coolers.